# How can I generate a video from a txt file and an image?

Tags: bash, audio, video, ffmpeg

Let's say I have:

- A txt file
- A 1920x1080 image

I would like to generate a video [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3v4uEvciMfs) where text is scrolling and audio is a given MP3.

I was digging a bit with ffmpeg but with no success.

Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

I gave a try to my favorite reading (3 paragraphs, wrapped to 80 characters)   :-)

```
lorem-ipsum-generator -l -p 3 -s 1 | fold -w 80 -s > TEXT
```

Then generate the video:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 \
       -i Blue-Planet-Earth-1920x1080.jpg  
       -vf drawtext="fontsize=20:fontcolor=white:fontfile=FreeSans.ttf:textfile=TEXT:y=h-200*t"  
       -t 8 output.mp4
```

*Explanations*:

- infinite loop as we have only one image (support multiple images in sequence, or piped)
- the [image](http://www.mrwallpaper.com/view/Blue-Planet-Earth-1920x1080/)
- the [drawtext](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1) is quite readable, animation done with usage of **t**
- "-t 8" for 8 seconds duration (at the end)

The text goes beyond the upper limit and continues to scroll upward.

Anyone can now generate it.

*(Thanks to FB !)*

Comment: What does FB mean?

Comment: FB is a glimpse to Fabrice (bellard.org)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [subtitles](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) filter with [Advanced SubStation Alpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubStation_Alpha#Advanced_SubStation_Alpha) (ASS) subtitles. Using the [`/move`](http://docs.aegisub.org/manual/ASS_Tags#Movement) tag will allow you to scroll the subtitles by providing beginning and ending `x`,`y` coordinates.

Advantages over the [drawtext](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) filter include more formatting options and the ability to automatically wrap the text. Disadvantage is that the `x`,`y` coordinates do not appear to be able to reference the text width and height, so you have to manually provide appropriate values in the `/move` tag.

[image]
<sub>Screenshot of scrolling subtitles</sub>

Example ASS file made with [Aegisub](http://www.aegisub.org/):

```
[Script Info]
; Script generated by Aegisub 3.2.2
; http://www.aegisub.org/
Title: Default Aegisub file
ScriptType: v4.00+
WrapStyle: 0
ScaledBorderAndShadow: yes
YCbCr Matrix: None

[Aegisub Project Garbage]
Last Style Storage: Default

[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
Style: Default,Arial,20,&H00FFFFFF,&H000000FF,&H00000000,&H00000000,0,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,1,1,1,5,10,10,10,1

[Events]
Format: Layer, Start, End, Style, Name, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Effect, Text
Dialogue: 0,0:00:00.00,0:00:05.00,Default,,0,0,0,,{\move(190,350,180,-90)}Draw subtitles on top of input video using the libass library.\NTo enable compilation of this filter you need to configure FFmpeg wit{\i1}h --enable-liba{\i0}ss. This filter also requires a build with libavcodec and libavformat to convert the passed subtitles file to ASS (Advanced Substation Alpha) subtitles format.
```

Example `ffmpeg` command:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex "subtitles=scroll.ass" -c:a copy -shortest output.mkv
```